# Angularjs edit and update options with javascript array of objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn angularjs. I have a javascript array of objects. I will add n objects into the array, later i will display in table.  When user click on edit on the row, current row details will be displayed in modal dialog box.

Now what is happening, whenever user changes the object property, it changes in the table also.

What i want

1. After clicking Update button, that object should get updated.
2. User can cancel the edit.

this what i have tried so far.

// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module('aa',[]);

app.controller('createController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isInEditMode = false;

    $scope.bookMarkObj = {
        providerUrl: '',
        providerTitle: '',
        ProdviderDesc: '',
        thumbnailUrl: '',
        isAlredyRed: false,
        IsSavedforLater: false,
        isShared: false,
        timeStamp: new Date()
    };
    $scope.ListOfBookmarks = [];

    $scope.addLink = function () {

        $scope.ListOfBookmarks.push($scope.bookMarkObj);
        $scope.bookMarkObj = null;
        $scope.isInEditMode = false;
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    };

    $scope.closeDialog = function () {
        $scope.bookMarkObj = null;
        $scope.isInEditMode = false;

    };
    $scope.editLink = function (currObj) {
        $scope.isInEditMode = true;
        $scope.bookMarkObj = currObj;

       $('#myModal').modal('show');

    };
    $scope.updateLink = function() {

        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    };


}]);
```

Even i have made plunkr version. Please some one guide me. [Plunkr-Edit/Update Angular JS](http://plnkr.co/edit/otYzrM7yvpnVFitVBXgQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the approach you followed while editing the object. in the editLink method of your controller, You wrote

```
$scope.bookMarkObj = currObj;
```

This actually copies the reference of currObj into bookMarkObj instead of creating a new copy.. Hence you instead have to use,

```
$scope.bookMarkObj = angular.copy(currObj);
```

I have created a fork of your original plunker. It solves your problem. Have made a few changes in your controller and html file.

Link to the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/cROa7JPXWllTZkslGXht?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://plnkr.co/edit/otYzrM7yvpnVFitVBXgQ?p=preview

The reason why it affects the underlying values in your plnker inspite of whether is because you are editing an existing reference of the object.

All I did was

```
$scope.bookMarkObj = angular.copy(currObj);
```

and then recorded the index. You can see that in the plnkr.